# How to hide connection details for mysql database in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I just began working with mysql in node.js and I am setting up my app.js project and I am trying to hide my connection details such as my ip, username, pw, and db name. I don't know how to go about hiding my connection details, so this is why i'm here.

I have tried to add the details in my `.profile`, but I keep getting an authentication error. But, when I include these same connection details in my regular app.js file, it works and connects to the database.

Here is what is being displayed in my app.js file:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
              host     : 'my.ip.address.info',
              user     : 'username',
              password : 'password',
              database : 'databaseName'
            });
console.log('Connected');
connection.connect();
```

I just want to hide my connection details so that when my site goes live in the future it is secured from prying eyes. I understand that leaving these connection details in my app.js file is not the correct thing to do, so that's why I'm asking for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `.env` file to set environment variables and use the `dotenv` package to surface them in your `process.env`.

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme

Create a file and name it `.env` and set your variables as such

```
host=my-ip-address-info
user=username
password=password
database=databaseName
```

Then you can access them like:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host: process.env.host,
          user: process.env.username,
          password: process.env.password,
          database: process.env.database
        });
```

You'll have to start your app with something like

`node -r dotenv/config your_script.js`

or add the following to the top of your entry script

`require('dotenv').config();`

I prefer the first method because those environment variables should be set by your host provider so there is no need for the `require` statement in your code.

Comment: Thanks, going to try this in a bit, but how does my host provider do this? I am using digital ocean, they don't really provide any support lol Also, I am keeping my mySQL db completely separated from my web server that I am going to be using to create my web app. Thanks!

Comment: I don't use DO but here's a quick google search on "digital ocean environment variables" https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps.  If you're keeping them separate (good idea), then create a `connect` function (or something similar) where you pass the parameters in.

Comment: It seems to be working, but not fully lol I keep getting an error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip-addr-of-my-db, ip-addr-of-my-db,:3306
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)

Comment: I have been trying to resolve this issue to no avail, and I'm not sure why it's throwing me this error when I revert the code back to how it was with my connection details exposed, it works, but when I try your method, it throws that error. I can't seem to find a solution :(

Comment: Turns out that it didn't need to be changed to mysql.createPool, instead I had to change the connection.connect(); line to connection.connect(function(err) {
});      thank you so much for your original answer! so happy!!!!

Comment: Don't add a comma to the end of lines in the .env file!

Answer (score 1):

I use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

```
yarn add dotenv
```

Create a .env file in the root directory of your project

```
host=my.ip.address.info
user=username
password=password
database=databaseName
```

Then from your code

```
require('dotenv').config();

let host = process.env.host;
```

Do not commit the .env file to a public repo.

Comment: It seems to be working, but not fully lol I keep getting an error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ip-addr-of-my-server-db, ip-addr-of-my-server-db,:3306 at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26

Comment: I have been trying to resolve this issue to no avail, and I'm not sure why it's throwing me this error when I revert the code back to how it was with my connection details exposed, it works, but when I try your method, it throws that error. I can't seem to find a solution :(

Comment: Check this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521755/errorerror-getaddrinfo-enotfound-mysql

Comment: yeah, this didn't help, I checked this too.  I guess i'm just going to have to expose my connection details because i've spent the last 3 days trying to fix this : /

Comment: Ha! So I figured it out, or rather figured out a workaround. I don't know why, but I changed mysql.createConnection(); to mysql.createPool();

Comment: Turns out that it didn't need to be changed to mysql.createPool, instead I had to change the connection.connect(); line to connection.connect(function(err) { }); I don't know why i had to add that but it works now!!

Comment: can you use this for client side JS? i.e. you can't use require there.